# How can I remove the "The page at (some website) says:" part of a popup?

Tags: javascript

```
alert("This is a test.");
```

[image: Sample popup]

How do I remove "**The page at stackoverflow.com says:**" part of a popup?

Comment: You probably can't as I expect it's hardcoded.

Comment: If it is my own website can i change it?

Comment: Yes, you can OVERWRITE alert popup. But you can always find better alternatives using jquery etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot remove this text in an alert, but you can fake an alert with something similar like a modal.